What am I doing wrong with my cactuses?
I have quite a few cactuses and recently have had some that have died. They have all have some weird signs that I wasn't able to find anything about on Google.
I've attached pictures, but some have orange spots, some have rotted from the bottom (and had pink or orange on the inside). I'm not sure what the problem is but I don't want it to spread to the rest of my plants.
I water them once every two weeks and there is a humidifier in the room with them. Any help would be appreciated! (I’m not able to attach all my pictures so here is a link to my google drive folder: https://photos.app.goo.gl/seV6GR3zkKy5wfC78)
Some images inline






I think that you are overwatering them.  A humidifier in the same room is not good.  They like dry conditions.  Make sure the soil is free draining,  If not, then mix some sand in it.  And water it less frequently.

Hello. That seems to be the consensus from a couple people who gave me recommendations. I will remove the humidifier. Thank you so much for your help!
